# Why does syslog create a user.log instead using syslog.log?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, elasticsearch, syslogd, filebeat

I have experienced something a bit weird for me. I have filebeat monitoring my rsyslog (`syslog.log`) file and sending it to my logstash.

I have noticed that after restarting filebeat where syslog is running, syslogs creates a new file  `user.log` under `/var/log/user.log` where my logging is going to. However, filebeat expects that `syslog.log` is the one updated, since that file is not updated nothing is shipped by filebeat towards my logstash...

So my question is that, why does rsyslog daemon create this other file `user.log`?

Any hint is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

regards

Comment: Because someone has configured rsyslog to log to that file.

Comment: How do you mean? I have also syslog.log and only when restarting filebeat, then rsyslog creates user.log

Comment: You will need to paste your rsyslog configuration. It's located in /etc/rsyslog.d/.